# Strange output from code calculating determinant of a matrix

Tags: c, matrix

So this is my code, it calculates the determinant of a matrix recursively using Laplace's expansion. When i print the answer it prints in the correct format but the numbers aren't right. I have no idea why and hopefully you guys will know more than me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* Define a determinant for a certain matrix and dimension size*/
double det(double **mattemp, int size);

/*Find the values for our matrix and it's dimension*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
FILE         *input;
int          i, j, pos;
int          dim=1;
double       **matrix;

/*Open File*/
input = fopen("matrix.dat", "r");

/*Check file isn't NULL, if good find the no of lines and hence dimensions*/
if( (input != (FILE*) NULL) )
{
    while (EOF != (pos = fgetc(input)))
    {
        if (pos == '\n')
        {
            ++dim;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    printf("********************\n");
    printf("Could not open file!\n");
    printf("********************\n");
    return(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*Close and reopen file and set the matrix*/
fclose(input);
input = fopen("matrix.dat", "r");
matrix=(double**)malloc(dim*sizeof(double));

/*Fill the matrix with values from the file*/
for(i=0; i<dim; i++) 
{ 
    matrix[i]=(double*)malloc(dim*sizeof(double));
}
for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        fscanf(input, "%lf", &matrix[i][j]);
    }
}

/*Close the file*/
fclose(input);

/*Print the matrix*/
for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
{
    printf("| ");
    for(j=0; j<dim; j++)
    {
        printf("%lf ", matrix[i][j]);
    }

    if(i != dim/2)
    {
        printf("|\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("| = %lf \n", det(matrix, dim) );
    }
}
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


double det(double **mattemp, int size) 
{   
double  dettemp, **temp;    
int     j, itemp, jtemp, jcurr;
double  column[size];

dettemp = 0;

if(size==1)
{
    dettemp = mattemp[0][0];
}
else if(size==2)
{
    dettemp = ((mattemp[0][0]*mattemp[1][1])-(mattemp[0][1]*mattemp[1][0]));
}
else
{
    for (j=0; j<size; j++) 
    {

        temp = malloc((size-1)*sizeof(*temp)); 

        for(itemp=0; itemp<(size-1); itemp++)
        {

            temp[itemp]=malloc((size-1)*sizeof(double*));
        }

        for(itemp=1; itemp<size; itemp++)
        {

            jtemp=0;

            for(jcurr=0; jcurr<size; jcurr++)
            {


                if(jcurr==j)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                temp[itemp-1][jtemp] = mattemp[itemp][jcurr];
                jtemp++;
            }

        }

        dettemp += (mattemp[0][j]*pow(-1,j)*det(temp, size-1));
    }   

    return(dettemp);
}
}
```

Comment: Probably isn't the problem, but you should not use `%lf` - just use `%f`.

Comment: Thanks, yer just changed it and it's the same :/

Comment: Actually turns out that making all of them %lf works, however now the value of the calculated determinant is incorrect

Comment: Hmmm, oh yes, I think that `scanf` functions require `%lf` for `double`, but `printf` doesn't allow it.

Comment: Updated the code.Now it seems like my values for the determinant are being multilplied by 1 million for 1x1 and 2x2 and are just wrong for 3x3 plus. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you certain that the values are being read in correctly?

Comment: Minor: `matrix=(double**)malloc(dim*sizeof(double))` should be `matrix=(double**)malloc(dim*sizeof(double*))` or better yet `matrix=malloc(dim*sizeof(*matrix))`.  You want `sizeof(double*)`, not `sizeof(double)`.  Likely does not make a difference as your mistake may give you too much memory.  BTW:  I like the last form to prevent this issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure as the correct values appear in the matrix when i run it, it's just the determinant that's wrong, I changed the above also thankyou.

Comment: I cannot see in `det()` where `mattemp[itemp][j]` is ever accessed?

Comment: Should i be accessing that? I'm so confused, why would it display the right elements but calculate the determinants completely wrong, even for the simple answers such as 1x1

Comment: I think all elements of the Matrix contribute to the determinant, so if one if not accessed, something is missing.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your suggesting i do to my code to make it work. Sorry, i've only been doing this for a few weeks :S

Comment: Aha - `return(dettemp);` is only in the last else condition!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return(dettemp)` in `det()` is misplaced.

Function needs to end

```
  }
  return (dettemp);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Can't believe it was that simple, this has been killing me for ages. Thankyou so much!!!

Comment: Double check you compilation output and the warning level you are using.  This issue should have flagged a diagnostic message all ready.